# Which media type should be chosen from HTTP Accept header when they have the same specifity, quality and level?

Tags: http, content-negotiation, media-type, http-accept-header

As you know you can add multiple media types to the HTTP Accept header. When it comes to the question "What type should the server return?" most explanations and the spec as well seem to only explain the algorithm to select the "preferred" media type based on the specifity, quality and level of the media type.

But what should be done when they are all the same? Say I have

- request 1) `Accept: application/vnd.company.v3+json, application/vnd.company.v4+json`
- request 2) `Accept: application/vnd.company.v4+json, application/vnd.company.v3+json`

Is the order important? I found [a blog post](http://apiux.com/2013/06/11/accept-header-quick-primer/) which states that, but couldn't find a source nor information about it in the spec.

Or is this undefined behaviour and it is up to the server to decide (e.g. always return the newest version) or return "300 Multiple Choice" (rarely seen in the wild) or something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The blog post is wrong; the ordering is not relevant. it's up to the server to choose, or, as you said, return 300.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought. But do you know of this is explicitly written anywhere?

Comment: The specification is RFC 7231 and it does not say that ordering is relevant.

Comment: Okay. So far I only saw this explicitly for `Accept-Language`: "Note that some recipients treat the order in which language tags are listed as an indication of descending priority, particularly for tags that are assigned equal quality values (no value is the same as q=1). However, this behavior cannot be relied upon."